# How to clean up memory for a unity program?

Tags: unity

[image]

I keep getting this error message whenever I try to run my program. I've already cleared my cache. Is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: Profile it and find out what is causing the problem. It could be underestimating allocations in a shader, a leaking piece of code, infinite recursion or a bunch of other reasons

Comment: Does it crash immediately &/or consistently at the same time after starting?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to allocate ~70 gigabytes of physics data? That's unusual. Can you walk us through what you're doing in your game that's pushing the physics system so hard? One way you can try to isolate the problem is to create a copy of your project, then start deleting assets and code until the problem goes away. The last thing you deleted before losing the ability to reproduce the issue probably had something to do with it. This helps you whittle down a complex project toward a minimal example you can demonstrate as a starting point for troubleshooting.

Comment: LevelManager.instance.Respawn(); it seems like that is the line of code that's making my unity crash

Comment: If you're hoping to get help with that code, you'll need to include it in your question. Remember, we don't know anything about your project except what you explicitly document here.